# Using LINQ to combine two lists by removing duplicates and retaining true bool values where present

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object with the following properties:

```
public class FormTypeRoleLinkDto
    {
        public int FormTypeId { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeAddedOn { get; set; }
        public bool CanBeAddedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Let's say I have two lists of items of this object type.

List 1 looks like this:

| FormTypeId | RoleId | CanBeAddedOn | CanBeAddedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True | False |
| 1 | 2 | True | False |
| 1 | 3 | True | False |

List 2 looks like this:

| FormTypeId | RoleId | CanBeAddedOn | CanBeAddedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | False | True |

I want to use LINQ to combine these lists in a way that removes any duplicate role IDs but retains the 'true' values wherever they were present in either list. So the end result would be a list that looks like this:

| FormTypeId | RoleId | CanBeAddedOn | CanBeAddedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True | True |
| 1 | 2 | True | False |
| 1 | 3 | True | False |

Is that possible?

Comment: concat, group by and aggregate or

Comment: @Selvin are you able to be more specific?

Comment: `first.concat(second).Groupby(P1,P2).Select(new C { g.Key.P1, g.Key.P2, P3 = g.Aggregate(...), P4 = g.Aggregate(...))` naive way ... you prolly wana use single aggregate for optimized version

Comment: Seems like a [full join](https://morelinq.github.io/3.4/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Extensions_FullJoinExtension_FullJoin__3.htm) with a distinct and select statement can handle this. Consider using [Morelinq](https://morelinq.github.io/)

Comment: in fact there is Max for for boolean so `....Select(new C { g.Key.P1, g.Key.P2, P3 = g.Max(P3), P4 = g.Max(P4))` will also work

Comment: @Selvin `Max` is both bad and confusing. Running on a boolean a Max is confusing to read and secondly `Max` will iterate all elements. Using `Any` is much better than either `Aggregate` and `Max` and it will go out as soon as one of the element is true

Comment: *Any is much better* no, it is not ... you need to iterate group twice ... `Select(g => g.Aggregate(new A { B = g.Key.B, C = g.Key.C },  (ar, a) => {ar.D |= a.D; ar.E |= a.E; return ar; }))` will do it only once

Comment: @Selvin your `aggregate` again if it has 10 items it does 20 compare, 2 `Any` will still do at MOST 20 checks. `Aggregate` is 2n while double `Any` is n+n  to 2n

Comment: `|            Any | 1.568 μs | 0.0184 μs | 0.0172 μs |`
`|      Aggregate | 1.350 μs | 0.0153 μs | 0.0143 μs |`
`| AggregateUntil | 1.423 μs | 0.0198 μs | 0.0175 μs |` ... well, you are wrong  ... where AggregateUntil is something like [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/29e24a8c72bbd76e2c273582839209dd) [whole test](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/84d739a65059dfafb80b0ef1b71a767f) ... again any have to iterate twice for D and E ... aggregate can do this in one iteration ... for worst case scenario Aggregate will be faster

Comment: [updated version with data which are in favor of the `Any`](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/84d739a65059dfafb80b0ef1b71a767f) with results  ... still `Aggregate` wins ... fun fact in dotnet 6 `AggregateUntil` is finally better

Comment: Posting tables of data is awful. Posting valid C# with your source data makes it useful for us to run and test our code.

Comment: @Enigmativity apologies, still learning the ropes over here. I will be sure to post code in the future.

Comment: @HannahHayes - No worries. It just makes it easier for us and it should be something you do before you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you need this:

```
var list1 = new List<FormTypeRoleLinkDto>()
{
    new FormTypeRoleLinkDto() { FormTypeId = 1, RoleId = 1, CanBeAddedOn = true, CanBeAddedBy = false },
    new FormTypeRoleLinkDto() { FormTypeId = 1, RoleId = 2, CanBeAddedOn = true, CanBeAddedBy = false },
    new FormTypeRoleLinkDto() { FormTypeId = 1, RoleId = 3, CanBeAddedOn = true, CanBeAddedBy = false },
};

var list2 = new List<FormTypeRoleLinkDto>()
{
    new FormTypeRoleLinkDto() { FormTypeId = 1, RoleId = 1, CanBeAddedOn = false, CanBeAddedBy = true },
};

var query =
    from x in list1.Concat(list2)
    group x by new { x.FormTypeId, x.RoleId } into gs
    select new FormTypeRoleLinkDto()
    {
        FormTypeId = gs.Key.FormTypeId,
        RoleId = gs.Key.RoleId,
        CanBeAddedOn = gs.Select(g => g.CanBeAddedOn).Any(),
        CanBeAddedBy = gs.Select(g => g.CanBeAddedBy).Any(),
    };
```

That gives me:

[image: results]

NB: I have assumed that `FormTypeId` is part of the grouping.

Comment: Asking out of curiosity: Is there any benefit using `.Select(g => g.CanBeAddedOn).Aggregate((b1, b2) => b1 || b2)` rather than simply `.Any(g => g.CanBeAddedOn)`?

Comment: @AstridE. - No, in fact I like that better. It short-circuits the enumerable on `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst.Union(lst2)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.RoleId, x.FormTypeId })
    .Select(a => new FormTypeRoleLinkDto() { 
        FormTypeId = a.Key.FormTypeId,
        RoleId = a.Key.RoleId,
        CanBeAddedOn = a.Max(x => x.CanBeAddedOn),
        CanBeAddedBy = a.Max(x => x.CanBeAddedBy)});
```

Comment: `Union` is bad choice ... if equality for `FormTypeRoleLinkDto` would be defined as only comparsion of ids then result would be only 3 rows ... where for `Concat` would be 4